# Perl sed file inside script

Tags: perl, sed

Suppose I need to remove every space in the first line of the file(or any other sed thing, doesn't matter). This would work if I do it from the terminal:

```
perl -i -pe 's/ //g if $. == 1' file.txt
```

But I need to do this inside a perl script. I can do this using `system`, but I find don't think this is correct solution to make system calls to perl from within a perl script.

Is there any way to make this work nicely and **without explicit file opening**?
P.S. There are, for sure, modules that can do that, but I'm interested in core functionality.
**P.P.S. I need to perform these actions on a file**

Comment: do you want to change the file?

Comment: Yes! I cannot think of reason why everyone think about STDIN. @Сухой27

Comment: Because that is what `perl -pe '..'` does.

Comment: How is that? With 
     perl -pe I am reading from file. Anyway, added -i.

Comment: `<>` reads from files given on command line (@ARGV >0), and from STDIN otherwise(@ARGV ==0). `-i` does inplace editing as stated in perldoc http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html

Comment: If you'd use `-i.bak` in the question, people would have known that you want to overwrite the files.  Since the code in the question writes to standard output, people legitimately assumed that was what you wanted.

Comment: Why do you need to avoid explicit file opening?

Comment: @Sobrique it's not that I **need** this, I just wanted to find more neat solution that a system call, and, for now, system call is the nicest one.

Comment: What do you mean by "neat"? Doing stuff implicitly rather than explicitly is a really good way of ending up with code that's hard to read, understand and maintain. It's not something that's desirable.

Comment: @Sobrique skip this question, please, if u cannot see what I'm asking.

Comment: Oh I can see what you're asking. I just think we've got an XY problem here. Which is why I'm asking questions to clarify what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

You can explicitly write what `-p` command line switch does,

```
sub pe {

  my $f = shift;
  local @ARGV = @_;
  local $^I = ""; # -i command line switch
  local $_;

  while (<>) {
    $f->();
    print;
    close ARGV if eof; # reset $. for each file
  }
}

pe(
  sub { s/ //g if $. == 1 },
  "file.txt"
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $line = <>;
$line =~ s/ //g;
print $line, <>;
```

**EDIT:**
Here's the in-place edit version.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

{
    local $^I = '.bak';
    while (<>) {
        s/ //g if $. == 1;
        print;
    }
}
```

Comment: print is a list operator, so that line prints the modified first line from the file i.e., $line and then rest of the lines from the file which are read-in via the <> operator.

Comment: I didn't knew that `print` also works like that way. Thanks.

Comment: No, it's not. Maybe, I wasn't clear, but I need to modify file, not STDIN,

Comment: That only works on the first line of the first file, not on the first line of each file.  The same applies to the code in the question, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```sh
$ # Setup
$ for number in {1..9}
> do
>     {
>     echo words are separated by spaces
>     echo lines follow each other
>     echo until the end
>     } > file.$number
> done
$ cat file.1
words are separated by spaces
lines follow each other
until the end
# Change the files
$ perl -i.bak -e 'while (<>) { s/ //g if $. == 1; print; } continue { $. = 0 if eof; }' file.?
# Demonstrate that all files are affected
$ cat file.1
wordsareseparatedbyspaces
lines follow each other
until the end
$ cat file.8
wordsareseparatedbyspaces
lines follow each other
until the end
$ rm -f file.? file.?.bak
$
```

It is easy to make code that affects the first line of the first file only (the [`continue`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Loop-Control) block deals with that by resetting `$.` at the end of each file in the command line).

Answer (score -1):

Iterate over the file using magical `<>` operator and change for 1st line.

You may try this:

```
while(my $fh=<>){
$fh=~ s/ //g if($.==1);
print "$fh";
}
```

Comment: Maybe, I wasn't clear, but I need to modify file, not STDIN,