# Pulling a sed script into a perl program

Tags: perl, sed, pdp-10

I need to shorten function names, so I identify them and produce a really long sed script that looks like this:

```
s/\breally_long_function_name1\b/A00128/g
s/\breally_long_function_name2\b/A00060/g
s/\breally_long_function_name3\b/A00035/g
s/\breally_long_function_name4\b/A00342/g
s/\breally_long_function_name5\b/A00203/g
...
```

and then call it like this:

```
`sed -i.bak -f $sedscript *`
```

The problem is that I can't depend on `sed` being able to handle those instances of `\b` and it seems messy.  Instead of writing out that sed script, I want to put it into an array and then do something like this for each line of each file I need to process:

```
$targetline =~ $processing;
```

My problem is that using `$processing` like that won't work and the `q`operators don't seem to do the job.  How do I massage this to get the substitution in `$processing` processed and the result put in `$targetline`?

Note: I used [Perl sed file inside script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32413831/perl-sed-file-inside-script) and the answer from @ron-bergin there to get this far.

The application for this is to convert modern-ish C code into a form that can be compiled by ancient C compilers.  The existing script is at https://gitlab.com/DavidGriffith/frotz/-/blob/master/src/misc/snavig.pl where it's used to prepare source code for compilation by KCC, an early C compiler for PDP-10 mainframes.  One of its quirks is that some symbols are limited to being 6 characters in length.  Background on this is at https://github.com/PDP-10/panda/blob/master/files/kcc-6/kcc/user.doc#L519.

Here's a fragment from a source file before processing:

```
void reset_memory(void)
{
        if (story_fp != NULL)
                fclose(story_fp);
        story_fp = NULL;

        if (undo_diff) {
                free_undo(undo_count);
                zfree(undo_diff);
                zfree(prev_zmp);
        }

        undo_diff = NULL;
        undo_count = 0;
        prev_zmp = NULL;

        if (zmp)
                zfree(zmp);
        zmp = NULL;
} /* reset_memory */
```

After processing, it looks like this:

```
void A00156(void)
{
        if (A00144 != NULL)
                fclose(A00144);
        A00144 = NULL;

        if (undo_diff) {
                A00155(A00148);
                zfree(undo_diff);
                zfree(A00147);
        }

        undo_diff = NULL;
        A00148 = 0;
        A00147 = NULL;

        if (zmp)
                zfree(zmp);
        zmp = NULL;
} /* A00156 */
```

Once processed like this, it is proven to compile with KCC and run on TOPS20 on both emulated and real PDP-10 hardware.

With my attempts to not use an external sed, instead of doing anything, I get nothing and then a flood of this when pressing ^C:

```
Use of uninitialized value $targetline in pattern match (m//) at src/misc/snavig.pl line 181, <$targetfile> line 104.
Use of uninitialized value $targetline in pattern match (m//) at src/misc/snavig.pl line 181, <$targetfile> line 104.
Use of uninitialized value $targetline in pattern match (m//) at src/misc/snavig.pl line 181, <$targetfile> line 104.
Use of uninitialized value $targetline in pattern match (m//) at src/misc/snavig.pl line 181, <$targetfile> line 104.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to organize a large number of replacements

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my %repl = ( 
    really_long_function_name1 => 'A00128',
    really_long_function_name2 => 'A00060',
    # ...
);

my $re = join '|', keys %repl;  # add quotemeta if needed. see text

while (<>) { 
    s/\b($re)\b/$repl{$1}/g;
    print
}
```

The [`<>` operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#I/O-Operators) reads line by line files with names given on the command line.  Each line, changed or not, is merely printed so this acts as a filter.  If the files need be edited in place then the code need be adjusted for that.<sup>†</sup>

If any of keys to use in the pattern can have symbols special for regex they should be escaped and a tool for that is [quotemeta](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta) --
`join '|', map { quotemeta } keys %repl`. But here the keys are names of functions in a C program.

This doesn't deal with some issues (what if some replacements are contained in others?), and may need other adjustments depending on details.  I don't quite get all points, in particular why the replacement list is printed to files.  If that is critical the replacement pairs above can be read from a file with a convenient format (a dump of a Perl data structure? `JSON`? Or `YAML` so that it is also nicely readable?)

The list is easily edited/extended by adding a replacement pair to the hash.

---

<sup>†</sup> One way is shown in the SO page linked in the question: set the [$^I global variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$%5EI) (value of the `-i` switch).  With it being an empty string input files are changed "in-place" but we don't get a backup, otherwise its value is added as a suffix to the backup files

```
local $^I = '';   # changes made to input files. no backup 

while (<>) { 
    s/\b($re)\b/$repl{$1}/g;
    print;
}
```

or

```
local $^I = '.bak';  # added suffix for the backup file(s)

while (<>) { 
    s/.../.../g;
    print;
}
```

Make sure to have this code in a small enough scope so to be able to use [local](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/local) to limit this change -- so that the rest of the interpreter isn't affected!

Or, handle the list of files manually if this doesn't feel good. Once a program is invoked

```
progname [options]  file1 file2...
```

then in the running program the array [@ARGV](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#@ARGV) contains all those words from the command-line (except from the program name).

As `@ARGV` is processed by `Getopt::Long` the dash-ed options (with `-` or `--`) are removed and what remains in `@ARGV` are `file1`, `file2` (etc) filenames.  So after `Getopt::Long` processed options you can do

```
foreach my $filename (@ARGV) { 
    # handle the file $filename
}
```

Or, copy filenames from `@ARGV` to safety in their own array and process from there.  (Or, one can make filenames a part of options so they will be extracted by `Getopt::Long`.)

If you handle files like this (instead of letting the "diamond" operator `<>` do it) then there are also libraries which can change a file in-place, like [Path::Tiny::edit_lines](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny#edit_lines,-edit_lines_utf8,-edit_lines_raw)

```
use Path::Tiny;

path($filename)->edit_lines( sub { s/\b($re)\b/$repl{$1}/g } );
```

Comment: No replacements are contained in others.  Each replacement is created and saved to a sed file according to `print $mapfile "s/\\b$symbol\\b/$newsym/g\n";` or `print $mapfile "s/$symbol/$newsym/g\n";`.  So far, I've been trying saving each line to an element on an array.  I think I see how using hashes instead can work, especially since the replacements are always in the form of `s/foo/bar/g`.

I've updated my question to show the exact purpose of this script.

Comment: @Frotz Thanks for the comment.  I'm still not sure why you write those regex expressions to a file?  If you want to have those in a file then writing replacement pairs in a dictionary format is better, I think. Can pick a file format that you find most convenient.  I edited the answer, have a look.  Added another way to do it, using a library.

Comment: That script started off as part of Adam Thornton's "gnusto-frotz-tops20" project (https://github.com/athornton/gnusto-frotz-tops20).  With his blessing, I pulled his script into Frotz proper.  I suspect he used sed out of expediency.  I've adapted your first solution to get the job done, but there's a problem that causes the script to stall at the beginning for around 45 seconds printing nothing before proceeding.  It shouldn't take more than two or three seconds to run.

Comment: @Frotz I see.  I didn't have time to go through the script you link in detail so I'm not sure of all that it does (and why it is needed). For the stated purpose -- to replace words -- not much more is needed than what I posted here.  I'll look at that script again

Comment: @Frotz "_a problem that causes the script to stall at the beginning for around 45 seconds printing nothing before proceeding_" -- don't know what that is about.  The simple code I posted won't stall...  And yes it should tak _at most_ a few seconds, since programming text doesn't normally come in enormous amounts

Comment: It could very well be that I did something dumb as this stall first appeared just before I went to bed.  The script's purpose is to allow a PDP-10 mainframe to run Infocom games. The C compilers available to it have interestingly strange limitations.  This script massages code to work around the limitations.

Comment: @Frotz Right, I did (sloppily) read through it now.  Clearly none of that is needed for this question, which you suitably simplified (to just how to organize replacements, right?)  So I can't really comment on all else in that involved script.

Comment: @Frotz On my quick read I didn't notice what would hold things up for an eternity (45 sec), but then again there's a lot of fine detail there.  And some curiosities.  I noticed an unchecked `open` (OK, if it fails it'll all break ... or will it? What else isn't checked?)  In the first place, why use `sed` _out of a Perl script_  -- Perl's only (_far_) more capable with regex, and more integrated processing should be better.  In the end I am not sure how much of that you actually need, but again I can only focus on what is stated as the question and that is simple

Comment: I managed to get your suggested code working by manually stuffing `@ARGV` with file names.  Unfortunately I can't get it to honor the `\b` boundary checking correctly.  Instead the old symbol is deleted outright. My latest jiggery-pokery is in the `snavig-fix` branch.

Comment: @Frotz "_by manually stuffing `@ARGV` with file names_ -- yeah, sometimes this is needed (then I'd advise to do it in a block and manipulate `@ARGV` as `local @ARGV = ...` so to not change the actual, global, one).  Just in case you don't know this: `@ARGV` is populated by the words from the command line (except from the program name).  So you can get filenames there by giving them on the command line.  I added a short discussion of this to the answer, for those who need to see it.

Comment: @Frotz "_can't get it to honor the `\b` boundary checking correctly_"  -- sorry, don't know what to say.  (I did glance at that branch but I don't have time to study that involved code.)  From what I saw when I looked at the program linked in the question it pre-processes target words a lot, manipulating the preceding  symbols to get only function names ... perhaps some of that messes with `\b` later?  If you can extract examples in which this shows that could be a new question.  I think that this question, as posted, has been covered.

Comment: @Frotz [cont'd] ... recall that `\b` matches a boundary between a non-"word" and "word" characters, which are `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.  So instead of `\b` you can form the list of characters that are the correct boundary in your case, if `\b` isn't suitable? Parsing programming text isn't easy, not even for seemingly simple things.

Comment: Matching with `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` will not work for a few places in the code.  For instance, there's a section with command line options with a line that looks like this `...(no startup messages)\n\``.  That gets changed into `...(no startup A00204s)\n\ `.   When I first noticed this, in `gnusto-frotz`, the resulting final program worked, just with `Axxxxx` stuff in some printed strings. Nothing was mangled that would have caused serious problems, but I'm not sure if that's still so because it was for Frotz 2.32 and the current version is 2.54. A lot has changed over the years.

Comment: @Frotz Target words in double quotes (or in comments!) are hard -- need a _natural_ language analysis to decide whether they refer to those functions in text (so should be replaced to their new names), or are just general words like `message` (inferred from your example).  However, `message\b` does NOT match `messages`? (Nor does `message[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`.)  The `\b` pattern would match the position between the `s` (end of `messages`) and `)` (as `)` is non-word character), but not between `e` (end of `message`) and the following `s`.  So I don't see how you'd get `A00204s` from `messages)`

Comment: (I assume that `message` is one of the names to replace, and with `A00204`)

Comment: Correct. That `message` is one of those symbols to be replaced.   The `\b` things are there to prevent matching `message` to `messages`.  This also happens with `interpret` and `interpreter`.  In a nutshell, if the word is embedded in another word (eg, has a suffix) then it should not be matched.  Identification of what symbols need to be shortened is done in the `build_symbolmap()` sub.

Comment: So, I've managed to get symbols like `message` replaced correctly; avoiding replacing `messages`.  There remains the problem of all `#include` lines including a double-quoted filename getting blanked out entirely.  Perhaps should I call this question complete and start a new one for the `#include`  trouble?

Comment: @Frotz "_filename getting blanked out entirely_"  -- so a `#include "filename"` should become `#include "fn01"` (to make up an example) but instead gets just removed (`#include ""`) ??  I noticed that that code deals with filenames separately but then that has nothing to do with this question?  If that's what you mean by "blanked out" -- that's not possible with regex used in this answer to this question as asked.  It either matches and replaces that with the corresponding value (since patterns are built with the actual replacement-hash keys), or it doesn't touch it.

Comment: The `#include` stuff is intended to convert something like `#include "../common/foobarbaz.h"` into `#include "foobar.h"`. It removes the path component and trims the actual filename to no more than 6 letters plus a one letter extension. I've repeatedly gone over what could possibly be getting into `s/($oldfilenames)/$includes{$1}/g;` to cause this.  It's like somehow `$includes{$1}` is resolving to a null string. Maybe this has something to do with `Use of uninitialized value within %transformations in substitution iterator at src/misc/snavig.pl line 212, <> line 13904.` errors, but...

Comment: (cont) those messages are printed if one, the other, or both substitutions are performed - and the symbols-to-Axxxx substitutions are fine.

Comment: @Frotz "_`Use of uninitialized value within %transformations in substitution iterator`_" -- ah, but that sounds just like what I mentioned: a matched pattern actually doesn't have an entry in the replacement hash.  But that is not possible for the code in this answer, because the regex pattern is built with the keys of the replacement hash (which is defined first) so whatever is matched _must_ have a value.  Clearly the substitution that gives you that error is done in some different way.

Comment: @Frotz "_emoves the path component and trims the actual filename to no more than 6 letters plus a one letter extension._" -- But for this you don't need, nor want, to use a pre-defined replacement (like in this answer).  It's a simple regex to implement this change.

Comment: @Frotz Like `s{ (?:.*/)? ([^.]+) \. (.+)}{ substr($1,0,6) . qq(.$2) }xe`.  (This may need adjustment -- or perhaps not)

Comment: @Frotz  Or `s{ (?:.*/)? ([^.]{,6}).* \. (.+)}{ $1.$2 }x;`

Comment: @Frotz To apply to the include line only:  `s{ ^\s*#\s*include\s*"\K ... "}{ $1.$2" }`, where `\K` tells it to drop matches previous to that point so they stay in the string and ellipses (`...`) mean the regex from previous comments.  All this may (or may not) need some tweaking

Comment: I'm not clear on the syntax for what you're doing with the ellipses.  If I substitute in `s{ (?:.*/)? ([^.]{,6}).* \. (.+)}{ $1.$2 }x;`, syntax error.  If I use `(?:.*/)? ([^.]{,6}).* \. (.+)` also a syntax error.

Comment: @Frotz "_not clear on the syntax..._"  -- just a minute...

Comment: @Frotz A command-line program ("one-liner"): `perl -wE'$_=shift//q(#include "../common/foobarbaz.h"); say; s{ ^\s*\#\s*include\s*"\K (?:.*/)? ([^.]{1,6}).* \. (.+)}{$1.$2}x; say'
`

Comment: @Frotz Or, for a path that _doesn't_ have directories `perl -wE'$_=shift//q(#include "foobarbaz.h"); say; s{ ^\s*\#\s*include\s*"\K (?:.*/)? ([^.]{1,6}).* \. (.+)}{$1.$2}x; say'`

Comment: @Frotz The one-liner above can take arguments, for testing: `perl -wE'...' "#include..."`

Comment: @Frotz What I had above _doesn't_ work, sorry -- I did say that it may need tweaking, didn't have time any more to test etc.  (Apparently, that `{,6}` can't go, need be `{1,6}`. It used to work in older Perls ...?)  There are other issues with this regex, edge cases which I didn't think about etc.  Perhaps better nicely split up that `#include` statement, replace the filename, then reassemble. It'll be three lines then instead of one, what is totally fine :) Or, at least please test a lot.

Comment: After testing more, I realized I was trying to do all this when tired and made silly mistakes.  I have the include files substitution working mostly correctly.  Still remaining is how to get rid of the `Use of uninitialized value within %transformations in substitution iterator` messages.

Comment: @Frotz "_working mostly correctly_"  -- great.  That remaining error you mentioned before. The best I can tell is what I said then: seems that your regex attempts to replace a match that isn't in the hash, which would mean that it's done differently than in this post.  If you: 1) build the replacement hash, _first_ 2) then build the regex alternation pattern _using the hash keys_ -- then whatever the regex matches _is_ in the hash.  (As done in this post, but there are of course other ways to do it.  I don't really know what you are referring to with that error...)

Comment: The "mostly correctly" part is that the included files substitutions don't account for collisions of, for instance, "foobarbaz.h" with "foobar.h".  The first is shortened to "foobar.h" and thus the collision.  The original sed-based solution did.  That's why it was done with sed rather than a relatively simple regex.  As of now the Frotz package has no header files longer than six characters.  So I'm safe for now.  Comment on your second part is coming later...

Comment: @Frotz "_account for collisions_" -- OK, of course.  Can also add that -- construct the new filename and then check for files with such a name; if any are found adjust the name, check again (etc).  Also keep a list of (new) names-to-be, from already processed ones earlier during that run, and check against that as well.  Again, i don't know how the whole thing is meant to operate and I don't know whether this is feasible.

Comment: I went over things again and again.  Processing the filenames included to avoid collisions when shortening them went back to using a big regex, just like with shortening symbols.  This, as with processing symbol substitutions, results in numerous `Use of uninitialized value within %transformations in substitution iterator`.  That being said, you've provided a solution to my question.  Unfortunately, clearing away that mess has revealed another.  Thanks.

Comment: After looking at this again 6 minutes later, it looked like my reply might be snarky.  That was not my intent.

Comment: @Frotz "_...snarky..._" -- oh, no, it isn't.  (I don't see why? I can absolutely understand you're unhappy with more problems, sorry about that. :(.  That error hits when we use `$hash{key}` -- but such a `key` doesn't actually exist in the `%hash`!  i don't know exact circumstances there but: if you build the regex pattern with the existing keys (like I show here) then _that_ error shouldn't happen -- once a match is captured it _is_ a valid key (because the pattern was built with the actual keys _only_) and so using it (for a replacement) should be fine.

Comment: @Frotz So with `my $re = join '|', keys %repl;` the pattern is `k1|k2|...` (etc, all hash keys) and so once `($re)` matches the `$1` has either `k1` or `k2` string or whatever key was there.  So then `$repl{$1}` exists.  I don't see how you wind up with those errors?

Comment: @Frotz One thought, just in case: there must be capturing parenthesis there. So `s/$re/.../` does not capture anything and `$1` is uninitialized (and errors follow) but it must be `s/($re)/.../`.  Possible to forget...  (There should be yet another error then though, for using the uninitialized `$1`, as well as for using an "uninitialized" (non-existent, that is) hash key.)

Comment: On snark, I thought it was coming across as "bleep you, you solved only part of the problem."  Back to what's going on, I found that when I got one of those complaints, it was because `$re` or `($re)` matched on the entire line and then that entire line was copied to `$1`.  So, of course, there was no match in the hash.  I'm not clear why the substitution that should have been done for that line wound up being done anyway. Eg, `void foobarbaz(int gruecount);` would be copied to `$1`.  That provokes a complaint.  Then `foobarbaz` is sent over, which works.

Comment: There must be something missing from `s/\b($oldsymbols)\b/$transformations{$1}/g;` that's causing this.  I don't remember where I found this suggested: `s/\K\b($oldsymbols)\b(?=.)/$transformations{$1}/g;` worked without making complaints, but missed a lot of symbols.  `s/\b($oldsymbols)\b/$transformations{$1}/g;` worked about as good as the first recipe without the `\K` stuff.  I thought the `\b` things would do the job of not making `$1` contain the whole line.  I've missed something in the translation from sed to perl.

Comment: @Frotz The first one depends only on how that `$oldsymbols` pattern is built. If every thing that it can match is a key in the hash then the regex itself is fine.  The second one doesn't make sense:  `\K` drops _previous_ matches so it is meaningless at the beginning, while lookahead `(?=.)` asserts that there is a character following whatever is before it (it's not the end of the string).

Comment: @Frotz More to the point, by now I don't see how these comments could be constructive; this is just not specific enough.  So I'd suggest to call this one done and come up with a short enough example of the problem so to post a new question.

Comment: I was getting to that point too.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Frotz Welcome, let me know if questions pop up.  One more thing that you mention that I meant to comment on and forgot:  "_I thought the `\b` things would do the job of not making `$1` contain the whole line_" -- yes, they should, as `/\bhi\b/` doesn't match `high` or `sushi` but only " hi " or `-hi,` (etc) . Or beginning of line or end of line work, so if the whole line is one word then `/\b\w+\b/` matches that whole line (without the linefeed character).

Comment: @Frotz Oh, I see your "_Back to what's going on_" comment only now! Escaped my attention previously. (And I saw no problem with the tone or inflections or any such  but thank you for being thoughtful.) I don't know what exactly is in your `$re`, and that could be a problem. As a silly example, a pattern `/\b\w+\s+(\w+).*;\b/` with your example line would: 1) match the whole line (`\b`'s are outside a subpattern that matches the whole line), and 2) put `foobarbaz` in `$1`

Comment: @Frotz [cont'd] If, on the other hand, `$re` were: `'foo|foobarbaz|more'` then `/\b($re)\b/` when applied to your example string (`void foobarbaz(int gruecount);`) would match `foobarbaz` (cannot match `foo` because of `\b` since `foo` in your string is followed by `b`, not by non-word character), and that's what `$1` would get

Comment: @Frotz That's why I think that a proper question would help at this point, as you can nicely spell it all out -- example text, exact regex you use, what you expect/need, and what you get.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254689/discussion-between-frotz-and-zdim).