# Getting rid of repeated "Use of unititialized value $foo in pattern match" errors in big set of substitutions

Tags: regex, perl, hashtable, substitution

I have a Perl script that builds a hash of symbols from C source files that are longer than X characters, then substitutes a string of `A[0-9]{5}`.  The number increments with each successive symbol to be shortened.  This is to prepare the code to be compiled on very old compilers with strange limits on the lengths of symbols.

In [Pulling a sed script into a perl program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76544979), I was able to get the old external sed script approach translated to work (mostly) directly in Perl.  The problem now is that I'm getting a complaint of

```
Use of uninitialized value within %transformations in substitution iterator at src/misc/snavig.pl line 210, <> line 8.
```

around 1600 times.  The problem is in this chunk of code, which applies the substitutions:

```
  my $oldsymbols = join '|', keys %transformations;
  my $oldfilenames = join '|', keys %includes;
  local $^I = '.bak';
  local @ARGV = glob("*.c *.h");
  while (<>) {
    s/\b($oldsymbols)\b/$transformations{$1}/g;
    s/($oldfilenames)/$includes{$1}/g;
    print;
  }
```

The `%transformations` hash looks something like this:

```
hide_lines => 'A00058'
message => 'A00165'
tokenise_text => 'A00388'
z_print_addr => 'A00220'
z_ret_popped => 'A00236'
encode_text => 'A00384'
```

I've tracked this down to the first part of the substitution matching on the entire line and it's put into `$1`.  So of course `compression_names[compression_mode], hide_lines);` won't appear as a key in that hash.  What I don't get is how to guard the `$oldfilenames` string such that `$1` will only receive one of the symbols in that string.  The substitutions in `%includes` doesn't provoke a complaint because the entire line will always match a key.

I don't remember where I found a suggestion to guard it with `\K ... (?=.)` or `\K ... (?=.*)` both in and out of the `\b` things.  These either did nothing or made messes.  What's the correct and effective way to get rid of those complaints?

Editing to add sample data:

Before processing:

```
/*
 * print_char
 *
 * High level output function.
 *
 */
void print_char(zchar c)
{
        static bool flag = FALSE;
        need_newline_at_exit = TRUE;

        if (message || ostream_memory || enable_buffering) {
                if (!flag) {
                        /* Characters 0 and ZC_RETURN are special cases */
                        if (c == ZC_RETURN) {
                                new_line();
                                return;
                        }
```

After processing:

```
/*
 * A00267
 *
 * High level output function.
 *
 */
void A00267(zchar c)
{
        static bool flag = FALSE;
        A00174 = TRUE;

        if (A00165 || A00162 || A00173) {
                if (!flag) {
                        /* Characters 0 and ZC_RETURN are special cases */
                        if (c == ZC_RETURN) {
                                A00266();
                                return;
                        }
```

Making substitutions within commented-out areas is fine.

Comment: The substitution shouldn't match the entire line, only the part of the line that matches $oldsymbols.

Comment: Do any of your hash keys contain punctuation characters that have special meaning in regular expressions? If so, you should escape them.

Comment: I know that shouldn't happen.  I'm trying to understand why that's happening and how to fix it.  The only punctuation character that appears in the keys is the underscore.

Comment: That has no special meaning, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I haven't used perl in decades. Don't you need to use `/e` to make it evaluate `$transformations{$1}` when it's making the substitution, not when it's substituting into the regexp.

Comment: So the problem is that you're evaluating `$transformations{$1}` too early, it's not using `$1` from the capture group.

Comment: @Barmar  "_Don't you need to use /e to make it evaluate `$transformations{$1}` when it's making the substitution..._" -- No, not for that, no need for `/e` -- `perl -wE'%h = (a => X); $_=shift//q(abac); s/(a)/$h{$1}/g; say'`

Comment: @Frotz Can you add some data on which that code fails? A short sample of a few lines would do.

Comment: `$1` cant possibly be `compression_names[compression_mode], hide_lines);` if the keys of the hash are "words" like those you showed.

Comment: Thank you for adding a sample to process.  So, when I copy your code into a program file -- exactly as given, and add the shown transformations hash -- and run it with your sample as a `.c` file I get that input file processed as wanted, with the only matching keyword, `message`, replaced (the rest of that hash doesn't correspond to this sample). No errors or warnings ...? This is perl v5.36.1.  Can you test and show code+sample that emits those warnings?

Answer (score 2):

There's information missing from your post, or some of the information is incorrect. (If this doesn't answer your question, you need to provide an actual demonstration of the problem.)

I'm guessing the issue is that you have keys with special symbols in them. For example, consider the case where you have a key named `foo*`. That will match `foo` (among others), which might not be in your hash.

You can verify that this is the issue by adding the following:

```perl
if ( my @errors = sort grep /\W/, keys %transformations ) {
   die(
      join "",
         map "Transformation key `$_` contains non-word symbols\n",
            @errors
   );
}
```

If that's intentional, you can replace

```perl
my $oldsymbols = join '|', keys %transformations;
```

with

```perl
my $oldsymbols = join '|', map quotemeta, keys %transformations;
```

But note that the anchoring `\b` won't behave as desired if a key starts or ends with a non-word character.

Comment: In a comment they said the only punctuation in the keys are underscores.

Comment: @Barmar, They said many things, not all of which can be true.

Answer (score 1):

> I've tracked this down to the first part of the substitution matching on the entire line and it's put into $1.

Your regex isn't matching complete lines, unless there is something in your real code that you haven't shown us.

I don't see a problem when running this

```
my %transformations = (
    hide_lines    => 'A00058',
    message       => 'A00165',
    tokenise_text => 'A00388',
    z_print_addr  => 'A00220',
    z_ret_popped  => 'A00236',
    encode_text   => 'A00384',
  );


my $oldsymbols = join '|', keys %transformations;
while (<DATA>) {
    s/\b($oldsymbols)\b/$transformations{$1}/g;
    print;
}


__END__

hide_lines
message
tokenise_text

compression_names[compression_mode], hide_lines);
```

It  does the right thing

```
$ perl try.pl 

A00058
A00165
A00388

compression_names[compression_mode], A00058);
```

Can you update the question please?